# My HP laptop shows a BIOS error

Tags: windows-7, laptop, bios

Sometimes, when I startup my HP laptop I get a message like this (I am not accurately sure of the message but it is something like this)

> HP Bios Startup error
>
> The selected bios file was not found. It is either corrupt or missing
>
> Please visit http://hp.com/go/techcenter/startup
>
> Please Press ENTER - to Continue.

When I press enter nothing bad happens, My system just starts up normally. I have had a similar problem with my desktop but whenever I press enter the computer restarts and doesn't startup. I was told that a virus had attacked my system.

I am very worried. Is the same thing happening here?, How will it affect my system? and What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suppose that your laptop bios is UEFI (Unified Extensible Firmware Interface). Most likely that the **HP_TOOLS EFI** is missing form the system. If you formatted/reformatted or replaced your HDD/SSD it could be that there is no **efi-partition (HP_Tools) installed**.

I think that correct error message is:

> The HP BIOS application selected is corrupt or missing. Please install
>   the application and try again.
>
> BIOS Application Error (501)
>
> Enter - Continue

To fix this do the following:

> 1. Enter your BIOS by pressing F10 (I think) while booting up
> 2. Navigate to System Configuration / Device Configurations
> 3. Find the option called **HP Quicklook** or **HP Quicklook 2** and set it to **Disabled**
> 4. Save the changes and exit

This should get past this message

Answer (score 0):

I occasionally have the same problem.
Usually, whenever I start up my laptop, I actually press the on button. When I don't, my fingers will accidentally touch the info sensor (an i with a circle around it,) and the message will show up.
Whenever I do press the button, that message doesn't normally show up.
Maybe try paying attention to what buttons you're pressing?

Answer (score -2):

HP PCs - HP BIOS Application Selected Is Corrupt or Missing

```
BIOS Application Error (501)
```

Here i am gonna tell you very easy way to turn your window ON that if this error shows then simply remove the power batter, Plug the power adopter cable & Press the "ON" Button your system will normally boot up so you can place the battery again with your system.